# Non macro based unit test frameworks

Tags: c++, unit-testing

`Bjarne Stroustrup` said in a video on CppCon that, one of his desires for the future of the language is to remove the preprocessor ecosystem from the standard.

I am looking for a unit test that is design is not macro based, but I am unable to found anything decent.

Does anyone knows about one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No decent ones currently exist, because there are still some things that are impossible to do in C++ without macros (e.g. getting a stringified version of an assert expression).  Before we can remove our usage of macros, the C++ language needs to evolve.  Check back in 10 years.

In the meantime, I recommend [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2).

Comment: I was looking at catch2 docs and it is seems to me like a fresh alternative to the already big ones. Thanks for the tip!